# How can I make this query more efficient by reducing index seeks?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a function which I want to be more efficient. I know that most of the cost is in seeking index. I want to know if there is a way to merge these two index seeks into one.

Here is my function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Search]
(
    @Query nvarchar(150)        
)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
    ID int,
    ResultPhrase nvarchar(max),
    Domain nvarchar(50)
)
AS

BEGIN

declare  @id int,
         @OffsetArticle nvarchar(50),
         @OffsetProfile nvarchar(50),
         @index int,
         @domain nvarchar(50),
         @StringResult nvarchar(max),
         @substrIndex int,
         @substrCount int,
         @field nvarchar(40),
         @begin int,
         @end int

        DECLARE pidCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR select id,OffsetArticle,OffsetProfile from PerfTest where contains (data,@Query)

        open pidCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM pidCursor INTO @id,@OffsetArticle,@OffsetProfile

        while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        begin

        select @index = CHARINDEX(@Query,data) from PerfTest where ID=@id

        exec @domain =  dbo.FindDomain @id=@id ,@index=@index, @offsetArticle=@OffsetArticle, @offsetProfile=@OffsetProfile


        if(@domain = N'Profile')
            set @end = SUBSTRING(@offsetProfile,CHARINDEX(N'-',@offsetProfile)+1,len(@offsetProfile)-CHARINDEX(N'-',@offsetProfile))
            set @begin = SUBSTRING(@offsetProfile,1,CHARINDEX(N'-',@offsetProfile)-1)

        if(@domain = N'Article')
            set @end = SUBSTRING(@OffsetArticle,CHARINDEX(N'-',@OffsetArticle)+1,len(@OffsetArticle)-CHARINDEX(N'-',@OffsetArticle))
            set @begin = SUBSTRING(@OffsetArticle,1,CHARINDEX(N'-',@OffsetArticle)-1)



        if(@index - 20 < CAST(@begin as int))
            set @substrIndex = @index
        else
            set @substrIndex = @index - 20

        if(@index + 150 > CAST(@end as int))
            set @substrCount = @end
        else
            set @substrCount = @index + 150 


        select @StringResult = SUBSTRING(data,@substrIndex,@substrCount) from PerfTest where ID=@id

        insert @result (id,ResultPhrase,Domain) values (@id,@StringResult,@domain)


        if(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            FETCH NEXT FROM pidCursor INTO @id,@OffsetArticle,@OffsetProfile

        end
        CLOSE pidCursor
        DEALlOCATE pidCursor

RETURN      
END
```

Comment: Index seeks are not your problem. That means it is using the index in the most efficient way. Your problem is that you are using a cursor. There will be a far more efficient set based solution. Let us know exactly wat you are trying to achieve with the function and we can help you right some proper set asked SQL

Comment: thanks for your answer.at first i want to know is there a way to combine "select @index" query and "select @stringresult" to one query because i do some logic on index can they both come in one query

Comment: and about my situation,i store all data about one entity in system in one large string in db and store offset of them (per table for example) in other fields of this table and full text this large table and here i perform my select query and find the offset of matched word and return result as table

Answer (score 0):

For combining the @index and @string result query, you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @results TABLE
(index INT, stringresult NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @results(Index,stringresult)
SELECT CHARINDEX(@Query,data) 
      ,SUBSTRING(data,@substrIndex,@substrCount
FROM PerfTest where ID=@id

SET @index = (SELECT index from @results)
SET @stringresults = (SELECT stringresult FROM @results)
```

This will read the perftest table only once, then read the results from a in memory table into the two variables

Comment: The @ substrIndex is dependent on the result of the call to dbo.FindDomain, which in turn takes @ index as input, so this solution is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Include

```
  CHARINDEX(@Query,data)
```

in the cursor, instead of calculating it first thing inside the loop. That should cut of about half of the seeks. While seeks are the most efficient access way for SQL Server, eliminating half of them is still going to help any query.

You could also try to include data in the cursor and calculate @StringResult using that value. If that is going to help is very dependent on the avg size of the data column. If it is small enough that should speed things significantly. What "small enough" is is dependent on a lot of things and you should try it out. If data is VARCHAR(1000) pulling it in the cursor it is most likely going to help, however if it is VARCHAR(MAX) with and average length of 2 MB it is most likely going to hurt.

Finally, as Pete mentioned, the best solution would be to write this in a set-based fashion, but that might be more complex, as you can't call a stored procedure from inside a single select statement.